# How to create a web hosted database with an offline feature(not on the internet)

Tags: mysql, database, web-hosting

I am currently busy creating a program which has its main database set as a web hosted MySQL database.(Project for university, so any help would be greatly appreciated) I need to create an offline feature(The program needs to be able to function without any internet). Is there any way to do this without adding an extra database for example an access database which stores all the data as well? Because this database needs to be included into the installation of my program.

Comment: Do you mean without any internet or any outbound network connections?

Comment: If you can think of a way of accessing a remote database without a network connection then GO FOR IT. Otherwise you will need a local version of at least some of the central database

Comment: @RiggsFolly hahah this is going to be a long descriptive message. I want to have an application that can save its data on a web server if that is what the user requires. I was thinking of something more along the idea of having the web hosted db which basically becomes a back up and a local MySQL db to be the actual data storage(I don't know how to create a local MySQL db, as it needs to be included in the installation, without using the server for MySQL, if that is even possible).

Comment: @Jeroen The user might only have temporary access to the internet. Thus it needs to be able to just be local.

Comment: Well installing a local MYSQL Server and database is not a big deal. In simple terms you just add the MYSQL installer into your installer. And then its just a case of Testing/testing/testing. on many target environments

Comment: @RiggsFolly how exactly how would I add the MySQL installer to the program's installer, and then just choose the client version? One of the biggest issues I am facing is having the database's details, in regards to the connection string, being generated.

Comment: I cannot tell you exactly, but most installer builders let you execute another install package within your the install you are building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an embedded [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org) or an embedded [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) database. In a lot of Java examples you will see these databases used.
By using such a database you will have no external dependency on a database.